# groovy Expando : why it consider the local variable and not the expando properties?

Tags: groovy, expando

looking at this test code:

```
def a = "test"

def expando = new Expando()

expando.a = a

expando.foobar = {a}

expando.a = "test1"

assert expando.foobar() != a
```

why the last assertion fail?  it considers "a" as the local variable and not as the expando.a properties.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I am mistaken, but when you invoke `expando.foobar()`, it returns the result of the closure that was assigned to `foobar`.  In this case, it is `a`, so it returns the value of a: `test`.

`expando.foobar()` does not call the property 'a' because closures do not look for their delegate unless a variable is not defined in scope (and in this case it is).

Edit:
If you were to do `expando.foobar = {delegate.a}`, that would return the results you are expecting.

Comment: @GrailsGui I agree with you, when i assign the closure to foobar it use the value of "a", but when i execute the foobar() method it is referred to the expando class so i was thinking it will look at the "a" property of the expando class, the scope in this case is the expando class, but i see i am wrong.  i was thiking the expando class like a class A { def a  def foobar(){ a } }

Comment: That is the case!  It's just that the 'a' in the closure is the local variable.  I updated my explanation.